# My df.to_sql is saying can't establish a connection to SQL Server. This is a local instance with no login creds

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I ran several df.to_sql scripts about 1 year ago, and everything worked perfectly fine, but now I'm getting an error that says the following:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (2)')
```

Here are two sample scripts that I am testing.

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
engine = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', host='CEDUMII6', database='TestDB', trusted_connection='yes')
df.to_sql('healthcare', engine, if_exists='replace', index=True, chunksize=100000)
```

and

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
engine = "mssql+pyodbc://CEDUMII6/TestDB?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"
df.to_sql('healthcare', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=True, chunksize=100000)
```

and

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
server = 'CEDUMII6'
database = 'TestDB'
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database +';Trusted_Connection=yes')
df.to_sql('healthcare', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=True, chunksize=100000)
```

My firewall is off! I must be missing something simple, but I can't tell what it is. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure your sql server is running?

Comment: Well, the Service is running, in the Services window, and I can run queries on tables, so I guess so.

Comment: Have you checked if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections?

Answer (score 0):

This is what ultimately worked for me.

```
import pyodbc
engine = "mssql+pyodbc://LAPTOP-CEDUMII6\SQLEXPRESS01/Test_DB?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"
all_data.to_sql('health', engine, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```